# On average, when do cats stop producing milk after giving birth?

Tags: cats, breeding, biology

As mentioned in my other question, [How can I get my cat to stop nursing on its mother](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6228/how-can-i-get-my-cat-to-stop-nursing-on-its-mother), I mentioned that I was not sure if the mother cat was producing milk, which could be causing my 9 month old cat to feed off her.

After giving birth, how long does it take for a mother cat to stop producing milk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mammals, milk can be produced when young need milk regardless of pregnancy although it isn't common.  In theory, a mom could lactate for as long as she liked as long as someone was nursing.

Usually in cats the mother starts to discourage nursing, which then stops lactation, not the reverse.

Comment: Anything I should do if the mother cat doesn't discourage it? Thats what strikes me as odd; it's as if the mother like it (she cleans the child while it's happening) Should I allow the little one to continue feeding off her? (although she's not so little anymore; about a year old) Keep in mind, she still eats dry cat food aswell