# Momma Cat dragging her older kitten to her newborn litter when nursing

Tags: cats, behavior, breeding

My momma cat just had a new litter of kittens. The newborns seem to be doing well. But Momma Cat keeps leaving them to come find her older kitten that is now about six months old. And trying to drag her in there with the smaller kittens. What can I do? Is this odd behavior?

Comment: Make a YouTube video of it?

Comment: Hi Amy did you find out why your momma car was doing this? I'm having exactly the same problem and want to understand why she is doing this, thankyouu

Comment: Maybe this question and answers is interesting for you: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6228/how-can-i-get-my-cat-to-stop-nursing-from-its-mother